# python how to pivot a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question on `dataframe`. So I have a table in `dataframe` looking like this
[image]

and I want to pivot it into this
[image]

I tried this code:

```
m = df['4'].str.match('\d', na=False)

out = df.where(m, axis=0).ffill()[~m].join(df[~m], rsuffix=('_')).iloc[:, :-1]

out.columns = range(len(out.columns))
```

and the result becomes:
[image]

is there a way to do that? I've tried unstack but seems doesn't not working as I expected. thanks all!

pivoting a pandas dataframe in python

Comment: What are columns names? `0,1,2,3` ?

Comment: column names are 1, 2,3, 4

Comment: It seems data related problem, what is `print (df.head(10).to_dict())` ? Can you add to question by `edit`?

Comment: Share the source file if U can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If last column is called `3` use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for identify headers of rows, replace next values to `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and forward filling missing values, add next values like new column in [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and remove last column by `iloc` with reaasign columns names in last step:

```
m = df[3].str.contains('\d', na=False)

out = df.where(m, axis=0).ffill()[~m].join(df[~m], rsuffix=('_')).iloc[:, :-1]
out.columns = range(len(out.columns))
print (out)
   0     1        2           3       4    5    6
1  B  RATE  England  02/02/2023  rate 1  3.5    4
2  B  RATE  England  02/02/2023  rate 2    4  4.5
4  U  RATE  England  02/02/2023  rate 1  3.5    4
5  U  RATE  England  02/02/2023  rate 2    4  4.5
7  B  RATE    Wales  02/02/2023  rate 1  3.5    4
8  B  RATE    Wales  02/02/2023  rate 2    4  4.5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I've tried your code but it only pivots the rows with 'B' and result look like                                                                                                                          B RATE England 02/02/2023 rate 1 3.5 4
B RATE England 02/02/2023 rate 2 4 4.5
B RATE England 02/02/2023 U RATE 02/02/2023

Comment: df.b.head().tolist() doesn't work with error message ' dataframe object has no attribute 'b'

Comment: this one doesn't work: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64'), error message is 'name int64index' is not defined

Comment: i tried m = df['4'].str.match('\d', na=False) but still it can pivot row starting with 'B' but not row starting with 'U'

Comment: I've edited my question by adding the result using your code, please could you have a look? thanks

Comment: @Lok - Is possible create dump of first 10 rows like dictionary and add to question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76686817/edit) ? `print (df.head(10).to_dict())` ?

Comment: One idea - if change `m = df[4].str.match('\d', na=False)` to `m = df[4].str.contains('\d', na=False)` should working.

Comment: {0: {0: 'B', 1: 'rate 1', 2: 'rate 2', 3: 'U', 4: 'rate 1', 5: 'rate 2', 6: 'B', 7: 'rate 1', 8: 'rate 2', 9: 'U'}, 1: {0: 'RATE', 1: '3.5', 2: '4', 3: 'RATE', 4: '3.5', 5: '4', 6: 'RATE', 7: '3.5', 8: '4', 9: 'RATE'}, 2: {0: 'England', 1: '4', 2: '4.5', 3: 'England', 4: '4', 5: '4.5', 6: 'Wales', 7: '4', 8: '4.5', 9: 'Wales'}, 3: {0: '02/02/2023', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: '02/02/2023', 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: '02/02/2023', 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: '02/02/2023'}}